# extracting a column from the text file containing headers and delimiters

Tags: python, data-extraction

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
~Date and Time of Data Converting: 15.02.2019 16:12:44
~Name of Test: XXX
~Address: ZZZ
~ID: OPP
~Testchannel: CH06

~a;b;DateTime;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;extract;l;m;n;o;p;q;r
0;1;04.03.2019 07:54:19;0;0;2;Pause;3,57263521596443;0;0;0;0;24,55957;1;3;0;0;0;0;0
5,5523894132E-7;2;04.03.2019 07:54:19;5,5523894132E-7;5,5523894132E-7;2;Pause;3,57263521596443;0;0;0;0;24,55957;1;0;0;0;0;0;0
0,00277777777779538;3;04.03.2019 07:54:29;0,00277777777779538;0,00277777777779538;2;Pause;3,5724446855812;0;0;0;0;24,55653;1;1;0;0;0;0;0
0,00555555532278617;4;04.03.2019 07:54:39;0,00555555532278617;0,00555555532278617;2;Pause;3,57263521596443;0;0;0;0;24,55957;1;1;0;0;0;0;0
0,00833333333338613;5;04.03.2019 07:54:49;0,00833333333338613;0,00833333333338613;2;Pause;3,57263521596443;0;0;0;0;24,55653;1;1;0;0;0;0;0
0,0111112040002119;6;04.03.2019 07:54:59;0,0111112040002119;0,0111112040002119;2;Pause;3,57263521596443;0;0;0;0;24,55653;1;1;0;0;0;0;0
0,013888887724954;7;04.03.2019 07:55:09;0,013888887724954;0,013888887724954;2;Pause;3,57263521596443;0;0;0;0;24,55653;1;1;0;0;0;0;0
```

I need to extract the values from the column named `extract`, and need to store the output as an excel file.
Can anyone give me any idea how I can proceed?
So far, I have only been able to create an empty excel file for the output, and I have read the text file. I however don't know how to append output to the empty excel file.

```
import os
file=open('extract.csv', "a")
if os.path.getsize('extract.csv')==0:
    file.write(" "+";"+"Datum"+";"+"extract"+";")

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    dat=[f.readline() for x in range(10)]
    datum=dat[7].split(' ')[3]
data = np.genfromtxt('myfile.txt', delimiter=';', skip_header=12,dtype=str)
```

Comment: How does the output is supposed to look like ?

Comment: Hi @AlexandreB., the output should be an excel file containing the values from the column named 'extract'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas` module.

- You need to read **skip** the first lines of your text file. Here, I consider not to know how many there are. I loop until I find a data row.
- Then read the data.
- Finaly, export it as dataframe with `to_excel` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Here the code:

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd

# Read file
with open('temp.txt') as f:
    content = f.read().split("\n")

# Skip the first lines  (find number start data)
for i, line in enumerate(content):
    if line and line[0] != '~': break

# Columns names and data
header = content[i - 1][1:].split(';')
data = [row.split(';') for row in content[i:]]

# Store in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
print(df)
#                      a  b             DateTime                    c                    d  e      f  ...  l  m  n  o  p  q  r
# 0                    0  1  04.03.2019 07:54:19                    0                    0  2  Pause  ...  1  3  0  0  0  0  0
# 1      5,5523894132E-7  2  04.03.2019 07:54:19      5,5523894132E-7      5,5523894132E-7  2  Pause  ...  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 2  0,00277777777779538  3  04.03.2019 07:54:29  0,00277777777779538  0,00277777777779538  2  Pause  ...  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 3  0,00555555532278617  4  04.03.2019 07:54:39  0,00555555532278617  0,00555555532278617  2  Pause  ...  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 4  0,00833333333338613  5  04.03.2019 07:54:49  0,00833333333338613  0,00833333333338613  2  Pause  ...  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 5   0,0111112040002119  6  04.03.2019 07:54:59   0,0111112040002119   0,0111112040002119  2  Pause  ...  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 6    0,013888887724954  7  04.03.2019 07:55:09    0,013888887724954    0,013888887724954  2  Pause  ...  1  1  0  0  0  0  0

# Select only the Extract column
# df = df.Extract

# Save the data in excel file
df.to_excel("OutPut.xlsx", "MySheetName", index=False)
```

Note: if you know the number of lines to skip, you can simply load the dataframe with `read_csv` using the `skiprows` parameter. [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. But how does this give the desired output? I need the values from the 'extract' column.

Comment: Uncomment `df = df.Extract`. You reduce the dataframe to the `extract` column.

Comment: Thank you. It works, however I cannot export it to an excel file. It seems that i have to install a package called openpyxl. Is there an alternative to export the output as an excel file? For some reasons, i cannot install that package on my computer.

Comment: You can have a look at the `xlwt` module. However, this is a new question.